# Map a different route by GET parameter in JAX-RS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

In Spring MVC, one may map different routes (methods annotated with the `@*Mapping` family) for the same base URI but with a different GET parameter, for example:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(params = "myParam=1")
    public void path1() {
        // Called when GET param "myParam" present with value 1
    }

    @GetMapping(params = "myParam=2")
    public void path2() {
        // Called when GET param "myParam" present with value 2
    }

    // Works fine!
}
```

I try to achieve the same routing with JAX-RS, but I fail to find a built-in way.

```java
@Path("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GET
    public void path1() {
        // Should be called when GET param "myParam" present with value 1
    }

    @GET
    public void path2() {
        // Should be called when GET param "myParam" present with value 2
    }

    // What is the missing piece?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-RS doesn't have the type of mapping that you're looking for - there isn't a way to match based on query parameters.  In general, the pattern is path based.  So in your example, JAX-RS is thinking more like:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GET
    @Path("/myParam/1")
    public void path1() {
        // will be called when the url ends in /test/myParam/1
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/myParam/2")
    public void path2() {
        // will be called when the url ends in /test/myParam/2
    }
}
```

However, having said that and expanding on @ACV's answer you could also do something like:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GET
    public Response routeRequest(@QueryParam("myParam") int myParam) {
        if( myParam == 1 )
            path1();
        else if( myParam == 2 )
            path2();
       // handle bad myParam

      return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

    private void path1() {
        // will be called when GET query param "myParam" present with value 1
    }

    private void path2() {
        // will be called when GET query param "myParam" present with value 2
    }
}
```

or a path based example very similar to above:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GET
    @Path("/myParam/{id}")
    public Response routeRequest(@PathParam("id") int myParam) {
        if( myParam == 1 )
            path1();
        else if( myParam == 2 )
            path2();
       // handle bad myParam

      return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

    private void path1() {
        // will be called when GET path param "myParam" present with value 1
    }

    private void path2() {
        // will be called when GET path param "myParam" present with value 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You just confirmed my fears. In the end I did the path based example with fixed values rather than `{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

You use QueryParam:

```
@QueryParam("param1") int param1
```

For example:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public Response getResponse(
        @QueryParam("param1") int param1,
```

You can also use regex in the `@Path`

`@Path("/users/{id: [0-9]*}")`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `@QueryParam` will indeed retrieve the value, but this will not affect the routing automatically.

Comment: Check my answer, you can use regex to filter out paths @kagmole